# How to identify duplicates in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an requirment that to identify the dupliacte values in the result data and append colour to it, where the Limit is of 10 records only(not to check duplicates in entire table).
Now my issue is how to find the duplicate in the respective result set.

I have tried in this way, But it's checking all table for duplicate. But, I want in within the limit checking.

```
    SELECT count(*)
    ,safer_id
    ,CONCAT (
        (DAYS_OPEN)
        ,CASE 
            WHEN (count(*) > 1)
                THEN '~#0a9ec1'
            END
        ) AS DAYS_OPEN
FROM table_gear
WHERE SAFER_ID NOT LIKE '%WYN%'
GROUP BY safer_id
    ,url
    ,DAYS_OPEN
ORDER BY Days_open DESC limit 10 offset 0;
```

Comment: Specify your RDBMS

Comment: where
and ? - is there some code missing here?

Comment: PostgreSQL is the Database

Comment: Edited P.Salmon

Comment: a) Please specify versions of your db servers. It's especially important for `mysql`
b) "where the Limit is of 10 records only" - if you have requirements for LIMIT than you must have detailed requirements for ORDER-ing. I see only `Days_open`

Comment: a) Version: postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.5.2
b)Ordering is not making any trouble @Ingaz. It's good enough.

Comment: Do you want 10 records only in the entire result set, or perhaps 10 records _per group_ ?

Comment: I need first 10 records for pagination

Comment: @UmaShankar Please specify the desired order of deduplication and pagination:  a) deduplication before pagination or  b) "after"?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `COUNT` as an analytic function here:

```
SELECT
    safer_id,
    url,
    CASE WHEN cnt > 1 THEN '~#0a9ec1' END AS color
FROM
(
    SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY safer_id, url) cnt
    FROM table_gear t
    WHERE safer_id NOT LIKE '%WYN%'
) a
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

This query conditionally assigns a hex color to those records which are duplicate with respect to the combination of `safer_id` and `url` values.  I'm not entirely sure about your limit or ordering logic, but you can easily modify what I wrote above to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tim. But I'm trying to execute, it's throwing error as t of undefined at t.* then I have given alias name table_gear is that fine?

Comment: Yes...I had an alias problem, but it sounds like you already fixed it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : I don't understand why `ORDER BY cnt DESC` - it does not deduplicate anything

Comment: @Ingaz The OP apparently also has the need to use `LIMIT`.  Using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is meaningless.  So there needs to be an `ORDER BY` clause, though it is not entirely clear _what_ that should be.